# How to save data in CosmosOS?

Tags: c#, cosmos

I'm working on a Cosmos operatingsystem, and I'm wondering if there is some way to write a file with information in it? I'm trying to make CosmosOS remind the username and the password.

PS. I also wan't it to be able to *read* the file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Currently only FAT is supported, so you need at least one FAT partition. In your `BeforeRun` method, you need to initialize the VFS, like this:

```
var fs = new Sys.FileSystem.CosmosVFS();
Sys.FileSystem.VFS.VFSManager.RegisterVFS(fs);
```

Then you can use the `System.IO` APIs to read and write files. The root path for the first partition is `0:\`.

### Example

```
public override void BeforeRun()
{
    var fs = new Sys.FileSystem.CosmosVFS();
    Sys.FileSystem.VFS.VFSManager.RegisterVFS(fs);
}

public override void Run()
{
    var usersFile = @"0:\users.dat";

    if (!File.Exists(usersFile))
    {
        File.Create(usersFile);
    }

    // now you can read or write to the file

    // example read methods: File.ReadAllText, File.ReadAllLines, File.ReadAllBytes
    // example write methods: File.WriteAllText, File.WriteAllLines, File.WriteAllBytes
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! It helps a lot, but I want to see an example of reading/writing files!

Comment: Added an example.

Comment: Thanks! That helped me a lot!

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue this worked for me

```
    using Cosmos.System.FileSystem;
    var usersFile = @"0:\users.dat";
    public static CosmosVFS FAT = new CosmosVFS();
    FAT.CreateFile(usersFile );
```