# C# Cosmos file system error "No partitions found!"

Tags: c#, operating-system, filesystems, cosmos

I'm trying to add a file system in my cosmos OS. When I boot my OS, I get the following error:

[image]

Here is all of my source code:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using Sys = Cosmos.System;
using Cosmos.System.Graphics;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace OperatingSystem
{
    public class Kernel : Sys.Kernel
    {
        Sys.FileSystem.CosmosVFS fs;
        // string current_directory = "0:\\";

        public void Save(string save)
        {
            string fullPath = @"0:\write.txt\";
            Console.WriteLine(save); 
            using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(fullPath))
            {
                writer.WriteLine(save);
            }  
            string readText = File.ReadAllText(fullPath);
            Console.WriteLine(readText);
        }

        public void check(string text)
        {
            Console.Write("Is that all you want to write [Y/N] ");
            switch(Console.ReadLine())
            {
                case "Y":
                    Save(text);
                    break;

                case "y":
                    Save(text);
                    break;

                case "N":
                    Run();
                    break;

                case "n":
                    Run();
                    break;
            }
        }

        protected override void BeforeRun()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Welcome to Print OS!");
            fs = new Sys.FileSystem.CosmosVFS();
            Sys.FileSystem.VFS.VFSManager.RegisterVFS(fs);
        }

        protected override void Run()
        {
            Console.BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.Blue;
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;
            Console.WriteLine("Print OS Version 1.0");
            Console.BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.Black;

            Console.Write("#> ");
            var input = Console.ReadLine();
            check(input);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have a FAT partition?

Comment: You probably also don't want the backslash at the end of the file name

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to save data in CosmosOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50100827/how-to-save-data-in-cosmosos)